# Display user data in numbered list

Tags: database, users

We sell a downloadable product. Each download requires registration and those who register for a download are assigned to a user role called "TFWPdownload". The registrants are further subdivided by hospital with a custom plugin. We bill the hospitals monthly based on the number of downloads. I can pull up the "TFWPdownload" users and sort the list by hospital name but for billing purposes I have to count the number of users for a particular hospital by hand. Is there a way to have the sorted list in the users admin display a simple sequential number by each user starting with "1"? In other words, if the sort produced 256 users assigned the TFWPdownload user role the list would start at 1 and the last user would be 256.

Comment: If there is it might be less complicated than figuring out how to run a query against your database which counts people with that role by hospital. You could easily pop this in an admin page it would show you the totals without you having to count anything

Comment: The query is already in the plugin. What I'm looking for is a way to display a sequential number beside each user starting with 1 after I sort by by the hospital name. It seems like it should be easy but php is way beyond my pay grade.